# How to send notification from wear os to mobile

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, android-wear-notification

I need to send notification from wear os to mobile. I searched a lot for this, every where it is for mobile to wear os, but I need wear os to mobile. If anyone has some knowledge about it or suggest some links, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's no platform-level mechanism for mirroring notifications from Wear OS to a linked phone. You'll need to build your own, with an app running on each device.

Comment: @String can you please suggest with any links to guide me.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer. For syncing notifications, I'm guessing you'll use the Data API (discussed on that page) - but the details will depend on the specific needs of your app.